# JComboBox TableCellRenderer seems to lose its value, although the value is saved

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

In order to get to this result:

[image]

I created the code below. But once the combo-box closes, whenever I click anywhere in the panel, the number seems to get back to 0 (although it does change in the code behind, as I see using `System.out.println(..)`).

This is the model:

```
public class MenuItem {
    public boolean getIsChecked() { return isChecked; }
    public void setIsChecked(boolean checked) { isChecked = checked; }
    public int getDesiredAmount() { return desiredAmount; }
    public void setDesiredAmount(int desiredAmount) { this.desiredAmount = desiredAmount; }
    public String getDescription() { return description; }
    public ItemType getItemType() { return itemType; }
    public BigDecimal getPrice() { return price; }

    private boolean isChecked;
    private int desiredAmount;

    private final String description;
    private final ItemType itemType;
    private final BigDecimal price;

    public MenuItem(String description, ItemType type, BigDecimal price) {
        this.description = description;
        itemType = type;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

This is the `JPanel` I use:

```
public class MenuPanelTable extends JPanel {
    private static final Integer[] allowedAmounts = new Integer[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    public MenuPanelTable(MenuItem[] items) {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20,20,20,20));
        JTable table = new JTable(new TableModel(items));
        table.setGridColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        table.setRowHeight(table.getRowHeight() + 5);

        TableColumn amountRow = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
        DefaultCellEditor cellEditor = new DefaultCellEditor(new JComboBox<>(allowedAmounts));
        cellEditor.setClickCountToStart(1);
        amountRow.setCellEditor(cellEditor);
        amountRow.setCellRenderer(new AmountsComboBoxRenderer(allowedAmounts));

        add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}

class AmountsComboBoxRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {
    private final Integer[] allowedAmounts;

    public AmountsComboBoxRenderer(Integer[] allowedAmounts) {
        this.allowedAmounts = allowedAmounts;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        out.println(String.format("(%d)->%s, [%s][%s]", row + 1, value.toString(),
                isSelected ? "S" : " ", hasFocus ? "F" : " "));

        JComboBox<Integer> cb = new JComboBox<>(allowedAmounts);
        if (hasFocus)
            cb.setSelectedItem(value);
        return cb;
    }
}

class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private final MenuItem[] items;
    public TableModel(MenuItem[] items) { this.items = items; }
    @Override public int getRowCount() { return items.length; }
    @Override public int getColumnCount() { return 5; }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex){
            case 0 : return items[rowIndex].getIsChecked();
            case 1 : return items[rowIndex].getDesiredAmount();
            case 2 : return items[rowIndex].getDescription();
            case 3 : return items[rowIndex].getItemType();
            case 4 : return items[rowIndex].getPrice();
            default: return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex){
            case 0 :
                boolean v = (boolean) aValue;
                if (items[rowIndex].getIsChecked() == v)
                    return;
                items[rowIndex].setIsChecked(v);
                fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
                break;
            case 1 :
                int amount = (int) aValue;
                if (items[rowIndex].getDesiredAmount() == amount)
                    return;
                items[rowIndex].setDesiredAmount(amount);
                fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        switch (column) {
            case 0: return "?";
            case 1: return "#";
            case 2: return "Course";
            case 3: return "Type";
            case 4: return "Price";
            default: return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0: return Boolean.class;
            case 1: return Integer.class;
            case 2: return String.class;
            case 3: return String.class;
            case 4: return BigDecimal.class;
            default: return Object.class;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return columnIndex < 2;
    }
}
```

How can I make the GUI stay in the selected value?

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) or it didn't happen.

Comment: @TT., sadly, it's not really possible with Java, especially w/ Swing... I tried to `Short`-en it as much as possible, so I removed lots of startup boilerplate. The `Short` value collides with the `Self Contained` value, but it is `Correct (Compilable)` example. People who know Java/Swing can build it in a matter of a few minutes (just add `Main` and container `JFrame`. Had I added them - it would've been longer...)

Comment: “[An SSCCE is] not really possible with Java” is a false statement.  Tons of Stack Overflow users have supplied Java SSCCEs.  Your code can be turned into an SSCCE with about twelve lines of code.

Comment: `just add Main and container JFrame.` - that is your job, not ours. Your question is about using a combobox as a renderer. All the other data/columns in the table are irrelevant to the question.  The MenuItem object is irrelevant. You implementation of the renderer is wrong. A renderer has no need for valid values, it just displays the value in the model. The combo box should only be created once in the constructor of the class.

Comment: `This is the model:` -  That might be an object stored in the TableModel, but it is not a model.

Comment: @VGR & camickr, notes taken. I will SSCCEE it asap.

Comment: [The SSCCEE'd version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41250620/jtables-jcombobox-cell-editor-sets-the-value-already-when-opening-the-list-eve)

Answer (score 2):

Remove `if (hasFocus)` from your renderer class.  You do want to show the value even when the cell doesn’t have focus, after all.