# JTable's JComboBox cell editor sets the value already when opening the list, even if clicked outside the combo-box

Tags: java, swing, jtable

`JTable`'s `JComboBox` cell editor sets the value already when opening the list, even if clicked outside the combo-box. Moreover, once certain value selected, next time the selection is opened, that value becomes the default:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new QuestionFrame();
    }
}
```

`QuestionFrame`:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import java.awt.*;

class QuestionFrame extends JFrame {
    QuestionFrame(){
        class Model {
            int num;
            private Model(int n) { num = n; }
        }
        final Model[] model = {new Model(9), new Model(8), new Model(7)};

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JTable table = new JTable(new AbstractTableModel(){
            @Override public int getRowCount() { return model.length; }
            @Override public int getColumnCount() { return 1; }
            @Override public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return model[rowIndex].num;
            }
            @Override public String getColumnName(int column){ return "NUM"; }
            @Override public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) { return Integer.class; }
            @Override public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) { return true; }
            @Override public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                model[rowIndex].num = (int) aValue;
            }
        });
        DefaultCellEditor cellEditor = new DefaultCellEditor(new JComboBox<>(new Integer[]{1,2,3}));
        cellEditor.setClickCountToStart(1);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(cellEditor);
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setBounds(new Rectangle(500,250,200,200));
        add(panel);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

It's somewhat makes sense, as `setCellEditor(cellEditor)` reuses the same `JComboBox` object instance, but I couldn't find another way to do it..

So how to solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is because the current cell value is not one of the possible selections of the combobox editor, and so the combo defaults to the first selection. If you change your editor to include the current values, e.g.,

```
DefaultCellEditor cellEditor = new DefaultCellEditor(
        new JComboBox<>(new Integer[] { 1, 2,3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }));
```

Then it works just fine and as expected.

If you want a more fine-grained control over the editor, then you'll want to roll your own and not use the default one.